# IIS8 - websites start automatically on Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, website, web-applications

several websites running on 2 different servers with win server 2012 r2 and iis8 keep starting by themselves after being stopped by me from IIS manager.

They keep starting after about 20 minutes from being stopped. even if I stop their applicatioin pools they keep on starting but not preloaded because I can see in the browser it takes longer for them to reply the first time I enter.
what I've checked:

1. Preload enabled = false
2. StartMode = ondemand for the AppPool
3. autoStart in configuration editor = false
4. browsing to the website when it's stopped does not start it, it is something else, more likely time based.
5. nothing in the Event Viewer, I can see that after 20 minutes of idle time, the app pool is stopped as it is supposed to do, but nothing related to it's start.

on another server, also 2012 r2 with IIS8, I have some web sites that stopped just fine. and the odd thing is they are set to StartMode = alwaysrunning, autoStart=True, preload=false.

I'm open to suggestions, what else to check? what did I miss?

Comment: now I've noticed that stopping the app pools acting the same as the websites, they keep starting after 20 minutes or so. independent of the websites

Comment: Windows/IIS by default won't do that. It is either a scheduled task or an application that tries to restore IIS from stopped, so no easy way to tell. You have tons of things to check, PowerShell DSC, Windows task scheduler and so on. You'd better open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com to see if Microsoft support team can help you out.

Comment: thank you @LexLi, I've checked scheduled tasks and didn't find anything related.